# WPF How to fill a wrap panel from a list

Tags: wpf, list, wrappanel

I have a List full of custom objects.

What i want to do is fill a wrap panel of usercontrols, a separate control for each object in the list.

Issue i have is:

The list can be edited by another thread, how can i setup so any changes to the list are automatically portrayed in the visible usercontrols?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just Bind an `ObservableCollection` to `ItemsSource` of your `ListView` which will hold your objects  and design your desired `DataTemplate` to display the parts of `objects`.Make sure you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FriendList}"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  >
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel></WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the ItemsSource of a ListView and define the ItemsPanel

```
<!-- MyControlsList is of type ObservableCollection -->
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyControlsList}"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel></WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

In your view model you should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and subscribe your ObservableCollection to the CollectionChanged event.  You can then raise the PropertyChanged event whenever your collection changes.

```
void MyControlsList_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    OnPropertyChanged("MyControlsList");
}
```